# How can I preserve the leading spaces in a string in bash when I cast the variable into an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, tabs

```
line="     Hello World!"
arr=($line)
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

> output : "Hello World!"

The Leading tabs/spaces are lost. How can I preserve them?
Could use some help with this , Thank you !

Comment: Quote it `arr=("$line")`

Answer (score 0):

Just quote the variable expansion:

```
line="     Hello World!"
printf '<%s>\n' "$line"
arr=("$line")
echo "<${arr[@]}>"
```